# Almost identical MySQL server totally different performance

Tags: mysql, performance-tuning, my.cnf

I have two servers which differ in mysql version

- Server 1 runs with `mysql 5.7` 2 cores Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6248R CPU @ 3.00GHz and 6GB RAM
- Server 2 runs with `mysql 8.0` 4cores CPU Intel(R) Xeon(R) Gold 6128 CPU @ 3.40GHz and 24GB RAM, since this is an
  **mysql only** server.

Server 1 runs in production, while server 2 is currently my development server.

I use a software, which sends e.g ~11k selects on my products table, which currently holds round about 150k products (so its not that huge).

My problem now is that **server 1** is done with the same task (same data) after 2mins, while **server 2** needs 18mins.

When I execute a single example select `SELECT link FROM products WHERE concat(sku, lieferanten_id) = '130928OR1';`

MySQL on **server 1** retuns an answer in 0.05 s, **server 2** in 0.06s

If I repeat the same select **server 1** is done after 0.00s, while **server 2** still needs the exact same amount of 0.06s.

Below is my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`

```
#Max MysQL memory: 662.8M

[mysqld]
user                           = mysql
pid-file                       = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket                         = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port                           = 3306
basedir                        = /usr
#datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                         = /tmp
lc-messages-dir                = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking

# GENERAL #
default-storage-engine         = InnoDB

# NETWORK #
max_allowed_packet             = 999M
max_connect_errors             = 100000
bind-address                   = 0.0.0.0
skip-name-resolve
skip-external-locking

# DATA STORAGE #
datadir                        = /var/lib/mysql

# CACHES AND LIMITS #
tmp-table-size                 = 1024M
max-heap-table-size            = 1024M
max_connections                = 100
thread-cache-size              = 64
open-files-limit               = 65535
table-definition-cache         = 4096
table-open-cache               = 4000
group_concat_max_len           = 320000
thread_stack                   = 1M

# TIMEOUTS #
interactive_timeout            = 300
wait_timeout                   = 360

# INNODB #
innodb-flush-method            = fsync
innodb-flush-neighbors         = 1
# innodb-log-files-in-group      = 2
innodb_redo_log_capacity       = 67108864
innodb-log-file-size           = 32M
innodb-flush-log-at-trx-commit = 1
innodb-file-per-table          = 1
innodb-undo-log-truncate       = ON
innodb-rollback-segments       = 128
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 18432M
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 4

# LOGGING #
log-error                      = /var/log/mysql/error.log
log-queries-not-using-indexes  = 1
slow-query-log                 = 0
slow-query-log-file            = /var/lib/mysql/mysql-slow.log

# CHARACTER AND COLLATION #
character-set-server           = utf8mb4
collation-server               = utf8mb4_unicode_ci
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = 1
```

Are there any values I totally tuned in the wrong way? Or is my **server 1** just "faster" because of MySQL 5.7, which uses query-caching?

If there is something I should also provide, please let me know

thanks in advance!

Edit:

my pastebin link contains output of  **mysql-tuner** and `SELECT name, count FROM information_schema.innodb_metrics ORDER BY name;` from my **server 2**

https://pastebin.com/yBScuLLZ

Comment: Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions). Your idea of "almost identical" is quite novel, I must add.

Comment: Agreed with mustaccio, there's quite a few significant differences between your two systems, especially the MySQL version which can directly lead to performance differences for the same query.

Comment: I added some information which are recommended by the mustaccio's advice.

I am going to install mysql 5.7 tomorrow on my server 2 and elaborate further. If there are still huge differences, Ill be back

Comment: I recommend never to use MySQL Tuner. It frequently gives incorrect advice.

Comment: Additional DB information request FROM Server 2, please. 
OS, Version? 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after completing your 11K prod select tests 2 times.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for speed improvement.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the configuration on each server.  And `SHOW CREATE TABLE` on each.

- If the query cache is on in 5.7, the second run of an identical query will take 0s.  8.0 has gotten rid of the QC; it won't run fast.  There are many reasons why the QC has been removed.  Your needs have not [yet] hit those reasons.
- The query in question needs to do a full table scan; hence it is not going to be very fast, especially the first time.  There are ways to speed up that query, but that is another discussion.

To delve further, please provide `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` and `SHOW VARIABLES` from each machine:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/mysql_analysis#tuning